# Sql Query Equivalent in MongoDB

Tags: mysql, spring, mongodb

i have this query in Spring MySql :

`@Query(value="SELECT if(Count(*) > 0, 'true', 'false') as bool FROM season c WHERE c.archived=0 and c.user_seasons_id=:idUser and :seasondate BETWEEN c.date_debut and c.date_fin",nativeQuery = true)
public Boolean existsSeasonDates(@Param ("seasondate") Date seasondate,@Param ("idUser") Long idUser);`

I need to change the body of @Query with mongoDB instead of MySql.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the data already in MongoDB?  If so, can we see a sample document?  On the surface, it looks like you only want true or false based on whether any matches exist, so `findOne` might do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should probably add a comment requesting more info from the OP instead of posting an answer but in the spirit of trying to translate that SQL statement into the equivalent MongoDB query (and data environment), this data:

```
var r =
[
 // IN: Only good one:                                                                                              
 { _id: 0, archived: 0, user_seasons_id: "U1",
   date_debut: new ISODate("2020-01-01"), date_fin: new ISODate("2020-01-06") }

 // OUT: seasondate is beyond date_fin                                                                          
 ,{ _id: 1, archived: 0, user_seasons_id: "U1",
   date_debut: new ISODate("2020-01-01"), date_fin: new ISODate("2020-01-03") }

 // OUT:  Right range, wrong ID.                                                                                    
 ,{ _id: 2, archived: 0, user_seasons_id: "U99",
   date_debut: new ISODate("2020-01-01"), date_fin: new ISODate("2020-01-06") }

 // OUT:  not archived == 0                                                                                         
 ,{ _id: 3, archived: 1, user_seasons_id: "U99",
    date_debut: new ISODate("2021-01-01"), date_fin: new ISODate("2021-01-03") }
         ];
```

processed by this simple pipeline:

```
seasondate = new ISODate("2020-01-04");
user = "U1";

c = db.foo.aggregate([
{$match: {
        "archived":0
        ,"user_seasons_id":user
        ,"date_debut": {"$lt": seasondate}
        ,"date_fin": {"$gte": seasondate}
    }}
]);
```

will yield just `_id:0`.